# Adding column to zoo object

Tags: r, zoo

I have a zoo object `z` with 10 rows and 2 columns as follow:

```
Date           Return
1986-01     0.00308215260513781
1986-02     0.00305355599484584
.                .
.                .
.                .
1986-10     0.00349830477430457
```

I need a `new` zoo object that contains the `z` object along with a new column `X` from data frame `df`. The desired output should look like:

```
Date            Return            X
1986-01    0.00308215260513781    11
1986-02    0.00305355599484584    12
.                .                . 
.                .                .
.                .                .
1986-10   0.00349830477430457     20
```

I used the following code:

```
new= merge(z , df$X)
```

However,  it gives the results not as desired but with each value in `X` assigned to each row of `z`. The `new` object now has 100 rows. It also removed the date column from the zoo object. Could not find where is the problem.

For a reproducible example:

```
# get the z object
structure(c(NA, 0.00308215260513781, 0.00305355599484584, 0.00166059811703964, 
-0.00511749445720536, -0.00145300480100395, -0.00171675339332211, 
-0.00335452754121814, 0.000189812976282344, 0.00349830477430457
), .Dim = 10L, .Dimnames = list(c("1986-01", "1986-02", "1986-03", 
"1986-04", "1986-05", "1986-06", "1986-07", "1986-08", "1986-09", 
"1986-10")))

# get the df data frame
structure(list(a = 1:10, X = 11:20), .Names = c("a", "X"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In your df you don't have a "date" column, so there's no column to match by. That's why every value of z becomes matched with every value of df$x, leading indeed to an increase in rows. As hendrik said, cbind might by what you want.

Comment: @Henrik cbind does the job, however, it defined the date column as a row.names which I could convert to zoo object. Is it any way to convert the new output to zoo object after using cbind? Also i have updated the data in the question to match the `dput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `z` in the question is not a zoo object.

Either of these will create a zoo object with `z` as the first column and `df$X` as the second:

```
read.zoo(data.frame(rownames(z), Return = z, X = df$X), FUN = as.yearmon)

merge(Return = zoo(z, as.yearmon(rownames(z))), X = df$X)
```

giving:

```
               Return  X
Jan 1986           NA 11
Feb 1986  0.003082153 12
Mar 1986  0.003053556 13
Apr 1986  0.001660598 14
May 1986 -0.005117494 15
Jun 1986 -0.001453005 16
Jul 1986 -0.001716753 17
Aug 1986 -0.003354528 18
Sep 1986  0.000189813 19
Oct 1986  0.003498305 20
```