# How to add a column to a zoo object?

Tags: r, zoo

```
library(tseries)
prices <- get.hist.quote(instrument='AAPL', start='2015-12-01')
prices[1]

               Open   High    Low  Close
    2015-12-01 118.75 118.81 116.86 117.34
```

How to add a column of a single value to each row?

```
                 Open   High    Low  Close  Symbol
    2015-12-01 118.75 118.81 116.86 117.34  "AAPL"
    2015-12-02 117.34 118.11 116.08 116.28  "AAPL"
```

How to add a column that is the result of a function? For example, `Sys.time()`?

```
                 Open   High    Low  Close                  Updated
    2015-12-01 118.75 118.81 116.86 117.34 "2016-01-11 09:44:15 PST"
```

I looked at [Adding column to zoo object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159966/adding-column-to-zoo-object), but did not understand the answer.

Comment: The data of a zoo object is a matrix and a matrix cannot be a mix of numbers and character strings.  If you want to add a numeric column then `prices$X <- 1:nrow(prices)` will do it.  You can add attributes: `attr(prices, "symbol") <- "AAPL"` but if you perform subsequent operations on `prices` the added attributes will not necessarily propagate.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the index to be a timestamp. An example:

```
index(prices) <- rep(Sys.time(), nrow(prices))

class(index(prices))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Whereas previously, it was:

```
class(index(prices))
[1] "Date"
```